# Mass/bulk update in rails without using update_all with a single query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to update multiple rows using single query of active record. I don't have to use update_all because it skips validation. Is there any way to do this in rails active record.?

Comment: you cannot do this on a single query because validations are applied to an instance of your model .. not on collection .. you can loop through all items and run `update_attributes` inside a begin block and rescue when validation fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mass update without using update_all can be achievable using activerecord-import gem.
Please refer to [this](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#columns-and-arrays) gem for more information.
Methods with [detail](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-import/0.12.0/ActiveRecord%2FBase.import).

Example:
Lets say there is a table named "Services" having a "booked" column. We want to update its value using the gem outside the loop.

```
services.each do |service| 
 service.booked = false 
 service.updated_at = DateTime.current if service.changed?
end


ProvidedService.import services.to_ary, on_duplicate_key_update: { columns: %i[booked updated_at] }
```

active-record import by default does not update the "updated_at" column. So we've to explicitly update it.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to update multiple records without instantiating the models, [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method should do the trick:

> Updates all records in the current relation with details given. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. However, values passed to #update_all will still go through Active Record’s normal type casting and serialization.

E.g:

```rb
# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
```

As I understood, it even accepts an array as a parameter, allowing us to provide different hashes to update different records in their corresponding order, like in SQL `UPDATE` statement. Correct me, somebody, if I'm wrong.

Comment: It does accept an array as a parameter, but it doesn't allow you to provide different hashes to update different records. I can't figure out what it does exactly, so I'd avoid using it that way =)

Answer (score -6):

It sounds like you are looking for [Update records](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-rails-activerecord/) - from the documentation Updating multiple records; different col with different data

You can do like this Example:

```
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

Comment: But for every record it will fire a separate update query, so what I want is that there should be only one query fired for all the updates.

Comment: No, This will fire only one query for your all records 
 `Person.update(people.keys, people.values)`

Comment: @RahulOjha if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up

Comment: @MayurShah sadly even in the docs and the link you provide they mentioned that their will be one query for each record: `For every record, there will be a query sent` (in the link you give)

Comment: yeah, Internally its execute one by one but it reduces the timing of execution.